# Remove invisible control

Tags: vb.net

(In VS 2008) I have a usercontrol that is in the properties list in Design view, but I can not see the actual control, and it creates some error. How can I remove it when I can't select it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Select it in the combobox at the top of the Properties window.  Hit Ctrl+F6 or click the tab of the design window.  Press the Delete key.

If it gets too hard to select then use View > (Other Windows) > Document Outline.  You get an easy to navigate list of all the controls on the form.  Right-click > Delete.

Editing the Designer.vb file would be another way, but it is riskier.  Click the Show All Files icon in the Solution Explorer window to be able to see it, open the node next to the form.

Comment: +1. Although should be `Designer.vb` not `Designer.cs` given the `[vb.net]` tag?

Comment: Thanks! did the Ctrl+F6, tab thing.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work, but try to select it through the properties window then just hit delete.

If that doesn't work, just switch to the source view an delete it there.